# Voltage Across a Resistor RLC

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

Given an RLC circuit I want to model the in- and out-of-phase of the voltage across the resistor  $R$ as a function of the frequency $\omega$ of the AC-supplied voltage  $U = U_0 \cos(\omega)$. The RLC components are connected in series, and the inductive coil of inductance $L$ has a resistor, $R_{coil}$,  connected to it as well (thus also in series with $R$).

So far, what I have is as follows:

Using Kirchoff's laws:

$$ U = I(\omega)R_{\sigma} + L \frac{d I(\omega)}{dt} + \frac{Q}{C}$$

and the equation for the frequency dependent current draw can be written as:

$$ I(\omega) = \frac{U_0}{Z(\omega)} = \frac{U_0}{R_{\sigma} + i\left( \omega L - \frac{1}{\omega C}\right)}$$

where $R_{\sigma} = R + R_{coil}$, $U_0$ and $C$ the capacitance of the capacitor.

The voltage across the resistor is then
$$ V_R = I(\omega) R $$

If I understand correctly, are the in- and out-of-phase components of the voltage $V_R$ simply the real (in-phase) and imaginary (out-of-phase) parts of the above equation? i.e.,
$$V_{R, real} = |I(\omega)|R =  \frac{U_0R}{\sqrt{R_{\sigma}^2 +\left( \omega L - \frac{1}{\omega C}\right)^2}}$$

What would the imaginary component look like?

A follow up question would be that if I was to measure the in- and out-of-phase components of $V_R$ using a [lock-in-amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock-in_amplifier), how would I use the equations above to fit the theoretical curves derived above to the measured data, if I did not have values of $C, L, R, R_{coil}$?

I think it might have to do with finding the resonance frequency $\omega_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}$ using the measured values of $V_R$ but I am not sure how this is possible.

Comment: Hint: to separate your $I(\omega)$ into real and imaginary parts, try multiplying the numerator and denominator by $R_\sigma - i(\omega L - \frac{1}{\omega C})$.

Comment: So $I(\omega) = \frac{U_0R_{\sigma}}{R_{\sigma}^2 + \left( \omega L - \frac{1}{\omega C}\right)^2} - i\frac{U_0(\omega L - \frac{1}{\omega C}) }{R_{\sigma}^2 + \left( \omega L - \frac{1}{\omega C}\right)^2}$